# Styling Help Framework

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I've read the documentation and I can't figure out how to override the help system framework that eclipse generates (eg. Search Scope All Topics etc).  It shows as a grey boring style, and the plugins seem to build it automatically.  I can add css to the toc.xml which affects my pages, but not the frame that goes around it.  Is there a guide for this?

Answer (score 1):

The modernization of the help system which is still based on HTML frames and which is not responsive has **not yet** been implemented (see [Eclipse bug 501718](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=501718)). Eclipse is open source and help is welcome. ;-)

However, it is possible to create your own responsive HTML 5 page with an iFrame for the content and which loads TOC elements, search results, etc. via JavaScript from the Eclipse help system as it is. In this way, I realized a search field with search suggestions and a preview (see [my blog post: *Like to pimp your help, eh?*](https://eclipsehowl.wordpress.com/2014/08/19/like-to-pimp-your-help-eh/)).